# ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: unhashable type: 'AnsibleMapping'

Tags: ansible, devops

I have been trying to get my first trial with templating with Ansible to work and I am stopped by this following exception. As far as I can see, I think I have maintained the indentation well and also validated the yml file. I don't know where to go from here, help pls! Below is the yml file followed by the exception I saw after ran the playbook.

```
---

- name: run these tasks on the host
  hosts:
    testhost:
    testhost1: "172.16.201.163"
  vars:
    ansible_port: 22
  tasks:

    - name: Templating
      template:
        dest: /etc/my_test.conf
        owner: root
        src: my_test.j2
      become: true
```

The output from the run

```
ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: unhashable type: 'AnsibleMapping'
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook", line 118, in <module>
    exit_code = cli.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.7.9/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/cli/playbook.py", line 122, in run
    results = pbex.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.7.9/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py", line 106, in run
    all_vars = self._variable_manager.get_vars(play=play)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.7.9/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/vars/manager.py", line 185, in get_vars
    include_delegate_to=include_delegate_to,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.7.9/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/vars/manager.py", line 470, in _get_magic_variables
    variables['ansible_play_hosts_all'] = [x.name for x in self._inventory.get_hosts(pattern=pattern, ignore_restrictions=True)]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.7.9/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 358, in get_hosts
    if pattern_hash not in self._hosts_patterns_cache:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'AnsibleMapping'
```

Comment: Ansible 2.7.9 uses Python3.7. How did you install it? Could you post the output of `ansible --version`?

Comment: ansible --version
ansible 2.7.9
  config file = /Users/xxxx/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/xxxx/ansible/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.7.9/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.2 (default, Feb 12 2019, 08:15:36) [Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]

Comment: @VladimirBotka - I couldn't remember how I installed this.

Comment: @VladimirBotka: Can you please suggest a plan of action for me as I am continuously hitting this one, would you recommend that I re-install ansible?

Answer (score 3):

There are at minimum two things wrong with the playbook you posted:

1. `hosts:` is a `dict`, but should not be
2. `testhost:` has a `null` value

[Reading the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-hosts) shows that `hosts:` should be a string, or `list[str]` but may not be a `dict`. Perhaps what you are trying to accomplish is best achieved via an inventory file, or dynamic inventory plugin/script

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. I isolated my "hosts" in to an inventory file and used the hosts list in the playbook.yml file to refer to the hosts from inventoory and this one worked ! I had to install libselinux-python package on all the remote nodes for the 'copy' to work, but the original issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also happen if you wind up with the wrong structure in your playbook.

For example:

```yaml
  tags:   # oops
    - role: foo/myrole
```

instead of

```yaml
  roles: 
    - role: foo/myrole
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in ansible playbook and roles
but the issue cause was from tasks/main.yaml file
remember ansible never guide you to the problem and even makes misunderstanding, you should find it yourself